# best mobile game development engine

Tags: android, ios

I'm new to game developing and really confused because there are a few engines for Android and ios.
I wanna make a 3D Android (and maybe ios) game and wanna know what the best engine is.
I'm using unity but I think unreal is good too

Comment: This is more a question for google than here. 
This is a compiled list of what's out there - http://www.develop-online.net/tools-and-tech/the-top-16-game-engines-for-2014/0192302. This is Unity vs Unreal and suggests Unity is better for mobile games so this could be good for you too - http://blog.digitaltutors.com/unreal-engine-4-vs-unity-game-engine-best/. You will find a lot more like this from google.

Stack Overflow is for questions about *programming* and does not support opinion based questions and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion Unity is the better option for mobile development as it's not quite so heavy on the device, plus there is a lot more documentation readily available for Unity. I have been using Unity for a few years and have never had a problem with it so far.